# Publish an alpha APK on google play developer console

Tags: android, google-play, android-testing

I want to publish my alpha APK on google's developer console. The question is whether it will be visible in the google play store? Or will it be only available for testers to whom I send the opt-in link?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: It will only show to that particular account where it is uploaded and to whom your sending apk link must added on play store (their Google Id)

Comment: Thanks! I must say that this is really not clear from googles documentation regarding the topic.

Comment: Yeah google never could create any clean UI, in any of their services, google play, google analytics, google maps api, google whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you publish it as Alpha version, it will be published on the Play Store but visible only for those subscribed to the tester program.

This is granted via the testing link provided when you link your Google+ community to the Alpha version APK.